# Azure deployment option with angular 5 application not compile and build in continuous integration

Tags: node.js, azure, angular5, azure-web-app-service

I am using Angular 5 ,bit-bucket ,azure app service and I have setup continuous integration with bit-bucket and Azure deployment option.

Please find following details

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Project structure

[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "vaquarkhana-poc-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build –prod ",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.41",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

**Question :** I don't want to add any build dependency folder into bit-bucket like

- node_modules
- dist

Since Azure build package.json during continuous integration however my build is keep failing during deployment .

Logs :

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build –prod `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the vaquarkhan-pos-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng build –prod 
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vaquarkhan-pos-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-21T05_08_50_688Z-debug.log
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.1.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Invalid start-up command "ng serve" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".\r\nMissing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated\r\nnpm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.28\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.6.0\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.\r\nnpm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"\r\n'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build �prod `\r\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\r\nnpm ERR! \r\nnpm ERR! Failed at the vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 build script.\r\nnpm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the vaquarkhan-pos-app package,\r\nnpm ERR! not with npm itself.\r\nnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:\r\nnpm ERR!     ng build �prod \r\nnpm ERR! You can get their info via:\r\nnpm ERR!     npm owner ls vaquarkhan-pos-app\r\nnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.\r\nnpm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200\r\nnpm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"\r\nnpm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\r\nnpm ERR! node -v v0.10.40\r\nnpm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28\r\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\r\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\r\nnpm ERR! errno 1\r\nnpm ERR! vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run build`\r\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\r\nnpm ERR! \r\nnpm ERR! Failed at the vaquarkhan-pos-app@0.0.0 postinstall script.\r\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\r\nnpm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-21T05_08_50_688Z-debug.log\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\75.10629.3460\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
```

I am wonder if anyone faced same issue and resolved ?

Comment: Make sure you’re running Node 6.9 or higher, if not then you need to update and problem will be resolved

Comment: If you see my package,json  , i am runing on 6 and above                                                                         "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tow points to fix

1. I see `node -v v0.10.40` in your error message, which is caused by invalid node version in Application settings. Set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `10.6.0` which is the only version available on Azure that matches your requirement.
2. Deployment with bitbucket makes your code built by Kudu, which requires your angular related modules in `devDependencies` to be installed on Kudu as well, need to copy them to `dependencies`.

[image]

Comment: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION =10.6.0 where should i add this , in package.json i have added   },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },

Comment: @vaquarkhan See my screenshot, the setting in package.json can't modify web app environment settings.

Comment: Thanks for quick response  ,building now ,will share results soon